# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I've faced a problem that is:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

How can I solve it?

This problem happen in `FindAll` method

```
articleViewModel.AttachmentFiles = AttachmentFileBLL.Instance.FindAll(c => c.ArticleId == articleViewModel.Id).ToList();
```

FindAll method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TModel> FindAll(params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TModel> items = RepositoryContainer<TRepository>().FindAll();

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                items = items.Include(includeProperty); // Problem occurred here! 
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

[image: Error location]

```
public virtual int? ArticleId { get; set; }

public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is  "c => c.ArticleId == articleViewModel.Id" you passed in to indicate an including path?

Comment: But is "c => c.ArticleId == articleViewModel.Id"  a right type for params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] includeProperties. I found your approach is pretty interesting, neer thought about it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an invalid argument to the [DbExtensions.Include Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) because it requires

> A lambda expression representing the path to include.

and not a condition like you've specified:

```
c => c.ArticleId == articleViewModel.Id
```

You need to call `FindAll` differently:

```
AttachmentFileBLL
    .Instance
    .FindAll(c => c.ArticleId)
    .ToList();
```

This would specifiy the property.

But as you also need to specify a navigation property for this you need to use such a property there. I don't know what name it can have in you model but something like this perhaps:

```
AttachmentFileBLL
    .Instance
    .FindAll(c => c.Articles) // Assuming 'Articles' is a navigation property.
    .ToList();
```

If you want to get only some items you should put the condition elsewere in some `Where` that would suit your needs:

```
AttachmentFileBLL
   .Instance
   .SomeCollection
   .Where(c => c.ArticleId == articleViewModel.Id)
   .FindAll(c => c.Articles)
   .ToList();
```